# Is PgQuery for QGIS still available?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I was wondering if PgQuery for QGIS is still available.  I am trying to install it on some new machines with QGIS 1.8.0 and I can not find it in the Python Plugin Installer.  Does anyone know of a place where I can download it directly?  Do I need to add a specific repository?  I currently only have the Official Repository loaded.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its still in the old pyqgis repository. Add

```
http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed
```

to your repositories. But it might be that it will not work as expected. The authors have not done much on it over the last years.